# Jquery .show not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery which will display the div on click of a button.

```
var parent = $(this)[0].parentElement.innerHTML;
$(parent).find('.divName').show();
```

`.show()` is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first line, you're getting the HTML string of an element.
At the second line, you're creating a new element using this string, then calling `.show()` on a virtual copy of the original element.

This is the correct way:

```
var $parent = $(this).parent();
$parent.find('.divName').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.innerHTML`, you targeted the text, not the element.

Also, I usually dont mix up jquery and javascript, here is the translated:

```
var parent = $(this).parent();
parent.find('.divName').show();
```

Also, can you show the full code?

**Edited**

Comment: JavaScript does not have a `.parent` method. `$(this)[0] === this`. Just remove `[0]`. In jQuery, `this` inside an event listener (the OP said "on click of a button."!) refers to an element. `$(this)[0] === this`, so `parent` in your case refers to a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving a jQuery object from a HTML string won't work. This should do what you want:

```
$(this).first().parent().find(".divName").show();
```